# npm install admin privileges issues

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install some npm packages, I am getting below error and my system is not having admin privileges. Please let me know how to fix this issue with out having system admin rights in my system.

> **C:\Users\gavvaru\git\guru\my-app>npm install eslint-plugin-import
>   eslint-plugin-flowtype eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin
>   -react npm ERR! path C:\Users\gavvaru\git\guru\my-app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall lstat npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
>   'C:\Users\gavvaru\git\guru\my-app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ge
>   tpass\node_modules' npm ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!  { [Error:
>   EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat
>   'C:\Users\gavvaru\git\guru\my-app\node_modules\fsevents\node_module
>   s\getpass\node_modules'] npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation
>   not permitted, lstat
>   \'C:\Users\gavvaru\git\guru\my-app\node_modules\fseven
>   ts\node_modules\getpass\node_modules\'\n    at Error (native)', npm
>   ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'lstat', npm ERR!   path:
>   'C:\Users\gavvaru\git\guru\my-app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\getpass\node_modules'
>   } npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator. npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found
>   in: npm ERR!
>
>   C:\Users\gavvaru\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-08-15T07_54_34_950Z-debug.log**

Thanks..

Comment: Try it again by opening CMD as administrator

Comment: Hi Jer, I dont have admin rights in my system.

Answer (score 3):

Try this command to solve it:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Comment: thanks Amol, it worked. Can you please let me know what is the issue and why we need to clean the cache.

Comment: Have a look at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache to know more about how npm manages cache

Comment: UPDATE: Running this command with the latest `npm 6.1.0` will generate this errror: 

npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guarante
ed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use 'npm cache verify' instead.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command with --force.